# Easy 'Recurrence' Flow Rather than SP Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I am  looking for where to plop the following formula in a 'Recurrence' Flow for an SP list. I need the Flow to fire once every 24 hours.

The SP calculated column formula (see below) currently works off the date in the SP default Modified column, and two list columns, "DateofCQ" and "Title".

I was told I could get rid of the calculated column on the SP side and perform the same task through a Recurrence flow on the Automate side.

Thoughts?

=IF(ISBLANK(DteofCQ),"Noncompliant",IF(OR(OR(OR(OR(Title="Driver I",Title="Officer I"),Title="Inspector I"),"Certified",IF(ISBLANK(CurrentDate),"Noncompliant",IF(AND(Title="Medical",DATEDIF(DteofCQ,CurrentDate,"d")<1095),"Compliant",IF(AND(Title="Fitness Test",DATEDIF(DteofCQ,CurrentDate,"d")<365),"Compliant","Compliant","Noncompliant")))))

Comment: Can we do a new one? Same process, but no multiple 'Titles'.

There is an Apparatus List. Each piece of apparatus has a unique license number ('LicNo' - Text). There is a Status ('Status' - Text) column. There is a 'LastPmpTst' column ('LastPmpTst' - Text). 

Each piece of apparatus needs to be pump tested every 365 days. I liked to create a Recurring flow to the SP list (once every 24 hrs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matiur Rahman:

I've gotten the flow to work. However, it shows every line with a date as 'Certified'. None are shown as 'Compliant' or 'Noncompliant'. I am providing screenshots of the flow.

[Flow Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvAVj.png)

[image]

[image: SP List Image]

Comment: I'm finally back to this; I re-wrote the flow. Got it to run successfully (so it says), and save. However, when I delete the Manual trigger and try to create the 'Recurrence' trigger I get the following error when I run the flow: 
Request to Azure Resource Manager failed with error: '{"error":{"code":"WorkflowTriggerNotFound","message":"The workflow '95e64206-c04a-40ab-b4a2-713025c67a75' trigger 'manual' could not be found."}}'.

Comment: @Matiur Rahman , any chance I can get you to assist me with finishing this flow?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing a number of similar requests for calculated column, which at times turns into a complex formula. Using MS Flow, it can be solved easily.

Let's first simplify the logic for the formula:

```
if(DteofCQ=null) then "Noncompliant"
if(Title="Driver I" OR Title="Officer I" OR Title="Inspector I") then "Certified"
if(Title="Medical" AND DateDiff(DteofCQ,CurrentDate,"d")<1095) then "Compliant"
if(Title="Fitness Test" AND DateDiff(DteofCQ,CurrentDate,"d")<365) then "Compliant"
else "Noncompliant"
```

**The Final Output of [Compliance Status] using MS Flow**
[image]

**Steps to Create and Schedule MS Flow**

1. For developing and testing, create an "Instant-from blank" flow
   and add "Manually trigger a flow" action. Later this can be changed to a Recurrence flow
2. Initialize few variables (screenshots will follow)
3. Add SharePoint action - "Get items" and configure it for your SPO site and list
4. Add "Apply to each" action to process each item in the list
5. Add "Condition" action to check blank [DteofCQ]
6. Calculate DaysDifference (in Days) between utcNow(),which is [CurrentDate] in Flow, and [DteofCQ]

```
DIV(sub(ticks(utcNow()), ticks(items('Apply_to_each')?['DteofCQ'])), 864000000000)
```

7. Add "Condition" action to check [Title] for *Driver I, Officer I*, and *Inspector I*. If true, apply "Certified" logic
8. If the condition in step 7 is false, apply Compliance logic for [Title] *Medical* and *Fitness* *Test* and *DaysDifference*, calculated in step 6.
   The expression for setting varcomlianceStatus is:

```
if(and(less(variables('varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent'),1095), equals(variables('varTitle'),'MEDICAL')) , 'Compliant', if(and(less(variables('varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent'),365), equals(variables('varTitle'),'FITNESS TEST')), 'Compliant','Noncompliant'))
```

**Screenshots showing MS Flow to calculate Compliance Status**

[image]

[image]

### **Detail 1**

[image]

### Detail 2

[image]

**To change Manual Trigger:**

- Delete "Manually trigger.." which will allow to select a new trigger
- Type Recurrence in the search and select "Recurrence Schedule" and configure the setting as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions or need clarifications on any of the Flow actions

---

### Updating to show blank for column [DaysCurrentMinusSteofCQ] when:

1. [*DteofCQ*] is empty or null
2. [*ComplianceStatus*]="Certified"

Here is the updated screenshot; Changes from the original post are described below

[image]

**Updated Steps:**

1. Initialize variable [varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent] with zero (0), step 2 in the original post
2. Move [Set variable - varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent] to the path where "Medical" and "Fitness Test" is compared as shown in the screenshot below. This was in Detail 1 in the original post

[image]

3. In the [Update item - update list item with the final Status], set column [DaysCurrentMinusDteofCQ] to the following expression. Detail 2 in the original post.

```
if(equals(variables('varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent'), 0), null, variables('varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent'))
```

4. Add *Set variable* action to set varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent to Zero (0)
   to ensure the next item's processing begins with a zero for this variable

[image]

---

---

**Updated screenshot with "does not contain" condition**
[image]

Comment: Wow, what a ride. I love it. I'll give it all a try today.

Can you add one more expression (is that the correct term)? 

The formula should force the 'Days to Renewal' Column to be blank for any 'Certification', as they are one time events. 

All qualifications (Medical, Fitness Test, etc.) are recurring and should show the Days to Renewal.

Can this last function be added in?

Comment: Also the formula I provided was old. I am now using the Modified column for the date, and not the Current Date. Does this matter?

Comment: At Detail 1 I have a problem. There are a total of 15 Certification titles. The Condition only allows for 10 'or' statements.

Is there a way to write it in negative? Can we ask 'if the CQTitle IS NOT 'Medical', 'Fitness Test', 'Live Fire Refresher', 'Self-Contained Breathing Apparatus Fit Test'...then...? <----these are the four actual Qualification titles.

If not, the flow can't be completed as demonstrated in the example while using all the required CQTitles.

Comment: Yes, you can use "not". Here's an example: if(not(equals(variables('varTitle'),'MEDICAL')), 'NOT MEDICAL', 'MEDICAL')

Comment: Since MS Flow doesn't need list items' "Modified" timestamp as it calculate days using the current date and time during the execution. Also, for your first question and I will update the flow and provide you a screenshot for that.

Comment: To keep 'Days to Renewal' column blank: In my example, set varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent variable to zero when DteoCQ is Blank, and also when status is 'Certification'. Then update the item with the expression:if(equals(variables('varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent'), 0), null, variables('varDaysBetweenCQandCurrent'))

Comment: Thank you. If you are working on an edited/updated example of the flow, I'll just wait for that, rather than try to figure it out and hope I'm right. I'm standing by; thank you!

Comment: Sir, is this still on your radar? Thank you!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly, Curtis -  are you referring to column "DaysCurrentMinusDteofCQ" in the first screenshot posted earlier to be blank for ComplianceStatus="Certified"? Please confirm - I've that and can post the screenshots

Comment: Yes. Though, I'm assuming that your 'DaysBetweenCQandCurrent' represents the data that will appear in my 'DaystoRenewal'.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I will post the screenshots and necessary updates on the Flow little later today

Comment: Updated the steps with screenshots. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Does this update reverse the 'logic', too? There were too many 'certifications' to list individually in the original condition. There are only four 'qualifications'; so I asked the question regarding the ability to reverse the logic to make this work. Does the update take this reverse into account? Does formula now ask only whether "CQTitle is Med, Fit, SCBA, Live Fire" for 'DaystoRenewal' content, and all others are blank?

Comment: My update is based on my sample. However, I've mentioned that you could use "not" function in the expression to update your logic. I don't have the up-to-date condition for your scenario, but if you could provide the complete condition in plain text then I might give it a try.

Comment: I think I understand. Let me try to build and test, to see if I'm actually learning anything. :-)

Comment: I provided an answer to my own question because I couldn't get all my response in this comment box. Can you please review my update or your update and comment? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, will take a look and let you know

Comment: I think you need to change "Or" to 'And" in the condition, because you have "is not equal to". If varCQTitle "is not equal to" [Medical] AND varCQTitle "is not equal to" [Fitness Test] then status is "Certified", right?

Comment: Another option to use "does not contain" condition, that is, building a string with Tittles for which status = [Certified] and then compare it with the varTitle. In that case, you need to switch "yes" path with "No" path. See the updated screenshot

Answer (score 0):

**Updated screenshot with "does not contain" condition check**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Made the change. The flow worked until it got to the final action "Set variable - varDaystoRenewal". The 'Set variable-varDaystoRenewal' value is DIV(sub(ticks(utcNow()), ticks(items('Apply_to_each')?['DteofCQ'])), 864000000000) and currently return '198' in the value field of the 'Yes' condition.

[image: Variable Image]
[image: Flow Error]

[image: Flow Image]
[image: Flow Image 2]

Comment: Curtis - the last action, that is, [Set variable-varDaystoRenewal] should be set to zero (0), because the next iteration should start with zero for this variable. You need to remove the expression and set it to zero.

Comment: Also, maybe it's failing within [Condition Action] as the last action, [Set Verriable-varDaystoRenewal], is showing green in your screenshot.  Are all 22 items are failing or a particular item only?

Comment: The only thing that show failing is the 'Apply to each' - "ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded. On run the flow errors out with a red check on thein the last action, 'Set variable - varDaystoRenewal'. The value of that field, when in the Flow Run Failed/Edit Review Screen shows a green '0' for 'inputs' and 'outputs'. I've provided additional screenshots in the Answer Question.

Comment: Can you delete the last action, [Set variable-varDaystoRenewal] , and then run the flow again? I know the result will not be correct, but just to see if it runs successfully. Is there any other action/expression in the upstream of the flow that this variable has  been used?

Comment: I hope that you've already resolved the issue. If not, I would like you to check whether you have any reference of 'Set_variable_-varDaystoRenew' in any upstream expressions in the flow as  error msg states it couldn't be evaluated. It might sometimes happen in copying and pasting expressions from one action to another. Unfortunately, it doesn't catch in saving the flow.

Comment: I can almost guarantee I did at least one cut and paste. I deleted the final DaystoRenewal action, as request, and ran. It errored out again. 'Set variable -varDaystoRenewal' is currently found in the Condition (Check for Qualificaiton Title) / 'Yes ' / Value - DIV(sub(ticks(utcNow()), ticks(items('Apply_to_each')?['DteofCQ'])), 864000000000).

Comment: I think it's still referencing some place that it's not liking it. You can create a backup copy of the existing flow using "Save as" and then experiment by deleting  [Set variable -varDaystoRenewal]  and adding a new [Set Variable] action at the same location and update the expression as needed to further troubleshoot. Not seeing the entire flow, it's hard for me to give you an answer.